# Adding a gif Image to a java applet?

Tags: java, applet, animated-gif

I'm trying to add a .gif image into my java applet but for some reason it just turns blank.. I'm using `getImage(getCodeBase(), "BLACK_Sel.gif ")` to get my .gif image, it worked fine with .jpg images but not a .gif image.. then to paint the .jpg/.gif I use

`g.drawImage(SelectedBlack,testx, testy, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, null);`

which, again, works fine for .jpgs. is there a different way I have to do this for an animated .gif image?

Comment: `g.drawImage(SelectedBlack,testx, testy, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, null);`  Should be `g.drawImage(SelectedBlack,testx, testy, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, Checkers.SIZE_Y / 8, this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Abstract Window Toolkit has a getImage() method that supports GIF.

```
Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("yourFile.gif");
```

Comment: still turns the spot blank and no .gif appears.. silly me.. for some reason after restarting eclipse my workspace was still out of date.. thanks :P

Comment: This will not work for a deployed applet since that method presumes the path represents a `File` whereas an applet (typically) requires an `URL`.